# Mirror moving of group of rectangles (how you change direction of moving)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was playing around with my code. I had one moving rectangle. I added if condition on coordinate X and Y.  like (posx and posy positon on x and y):

```
if (!go_down) {
    if (posx < 250 && go_right) {
        posx += 3;
    } else if (posx < 30) {
        go_right = true;
        go_down = true;
    } else if (!go_right) {
        posx -= 3;
    } else {
        go_right = false;
        go_down = true;
    }
} else {
    //if(posy <= 30)
    posy += 5;
    go_down = false;
}
```

As you can see my rectangle used to go down. Well I decided created an array of objects and tried to implement my IF condition with them.... But they do not work the same......Any suggestions? any help appreciated....

```
window.onload = function () {

    function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.fill = fill;
    }

    // get canvas element.
    var elem = document.getElementById('paper');
    context = elem.getContext('2d');
    //var container = {x:100, y:100, width:1200, height: 800};
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(250, 450, 40, 40);

    // check if context exist
    if (elem.getContext) {

        var array = [];
        array.push(new Shape(20, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(20, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(20, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(80, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(80, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(80, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(140, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(140, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(140, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
        //context = elem.getContext('2d');
    }

    //function draw (){
    // context.fillStyle = 'red'; 
    //context.fillRect(container.x, container.y, container.width, container,height);
    //}
    var go_right = true;
    var go_down = false;
    setInterval(function () {

        /// clear canvas for each frame
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);

        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fillRect(250, 450, 40, 40);

        /// iterate object array and move all objects
        for (var i = 0, oRec; oRec = array[i]; i++) {
            oRec.x++; /// update each object's position

            context.fillStyle = oRec.fill;
            context.fillRect(oRec.x, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);

            if (!go_down) {
                if (oRec.x < 250 && go_right) {
                    oRec.x += 3;
                } else if (oRec.x < 30) {
                    go_right = true;
                    go_down = true;
                } else if (!go_right) {
                    oRec.x -= 3;
                } else {
                    go_right = false;
                    go_down = true;
                }
            } else {

                oRec.y += 5;
                go_down = false;
            }
        }
    }, 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

A traditional way of moving objects on canvas is to:

- Define its current position (x,y).
- Define its velocity, which is how much it moves during each animation frame.
- Separately define its direction, which is whether its moving left-or-right and up-or-down.

So your rect object(s) might be defined like this:

```
var rect={
    x:10,
    y:10,
    velocityX:3,
    velocityY:4,
    directionX:1,
    directionY:1
};
```

So inside your animation frame you can move your rect like this:

```
rect.x += velocityX * directionX;

rect.y += velocityY * directionY;
```

Since the directionX and directionY initially are 1, your rect moves rightward by 3 and downward by 4.

When you want to reverse your rect's direction you just multiply its directionX or directionY by -1.

```
rect.directionX *= -1;

rect.directionY *= -1;
```

Now your rect moves leftward by 3 and upward by 4.

The key is to separate your rect (or array of rects) velocity from its direction.

If you want an array of rects to all move in the same direction just iterate the array and change all their directionX and/or directionY to be the same.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score -1):

var array = [];

```
                  array.push(new Shape(20, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(20, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(20, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(80, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(80, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(80, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(140, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(140, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(140, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
                  //context = elem.getContext('2d');
                  }

                  //function draw (){
                   // context.fillStyle = 'red'; 
                    //context.fillRect(container.x, container.y, container.width, container,height);
                     //}


                var go_right = true;
                 var go_down = false;
                setInterval( function(){


                /// clear canvas for each frame

                 context.fillStyle = 'black';
          context.fillRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);

             context.fillStyle = "white";
```

Comment: Please post well formatted code snippets (clear comments and proper indentation). Use as less code as possible, just enough to show your answer.